# Possible to add JUnit 'Failed' Test Images to TFS Dashboard?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, tfs, webdriver

Possible to add JUnit Failed Test Images to TFS?

1. My TFS Dashboard executes my webdriver test suites
2. Once all tests have executed within the test suite batches the TFS will then read the outputted JUnit results
3. When there is a test failure the TFS dashboard will highlight the failed test as illustrated within the image below.
4. Does anyone know how i can bind 'failed' images to the JUnit report and in turn link the image to a test which fails? 
   [image]
   [image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you generate the failed image? Or do you mean you want to save the Pass&Fail test status in your first screenshot as image and then add to "Attachments"?

Comment: @Eddie thanks for the message, ideally i would like each test marked as a fail within the JUnit xml to have its own unique image which will in turn get fed to the TFS and assigned to the relevant issue.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to achieve this feature by default. You have to add a PowerShell task or [create your own build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) to upload the image to the related test result by calling [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/attachments#attach-a-file-to-a-test-result).