# How do I include screenshots in Junit report with WebdriverIo

Tags: javascript, junit, webdriver-io

I am using:
**webdriver.io** and **wdio-junit-reporter** as a reporter. 
In the `afterTest`-Hook I am generating a screenshot in case a test fails.
How can I embed this screenshot in the automatically generated Junit reports?
Inside the `afterTest`-Hook I don't seem to be able to access the Junit Reporter.
My goal is to have see the Screenshot along the stacktraces inside Jenkins using the JUnit Reports Plugin.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: No - still searching for a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43244839/2589021 It doesn't seem to have a default way according to this answer.